# Jquery ui tabs in magentos list.phtml

Tags: jquery, magento, jquery-ui-tabs, magento-1.8

I'm trying to use the jquery ui tabs within the magento list.phtml page. 
Here's a link to the [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p6Vxh/). It also works fine on my local html test file.

I did exactly what was suggested [here](http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-jquery-how-to-use-them-together/) with the difference that I included four js files in page.xml.

```
<action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/jquery-1.10.2.js</name></action>
<action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/jquery.ui.core.js</name></action>
<action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/jquery.ui.widget.js</name></action>
<action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/jquery.ui.tabs.js</name></action>
```

The files are in the directory skin\frontend\default\myTheme\js\

My Javascript code is in list.phtml, as well as the html for the tabs. 
What am I doing wrong?

###### EDIT:

I finally got it working (but still don't really understand why). In the end the following settings worked for me: 
directly include the js files via `<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('js/jquery-1.10.2.js') ?>"></script>` into list.phtml and changing all `$` to `jQuery`

No `jQuery.noConflict();` needed, works without this call, or maybe is called from another js file/code snippet.

Comment: Did you use Jquery no conflict as mentioned in the link?

Comment: yes. I added `<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.noConflict();
</script>` to the bottom of head.phtml as mentioned in the link

Comment: Try replacing "$" with "jQuery".

Comment: did not help. To me it seems as if the jquery is not addressed. If I click the tabs, it behaves more like an anchor. The page is just "jumping", but no functionality.

Comment: What is the error ? Which part is not working for you?

Comment: If I click a tab, I want the content of the second tab to fade in like in the fiddle. Right now, if I click a tab nothing happens, except the jumping. No change of content or fading.